# Cпособы перевода полей классов jpa-сущностей в json-type

Tags: java, json, hibernate

Здравствуйте, подскажите какие есть способы перевода полей классов jpa-сущностей (конкретно используем hibernate) в json-type свойства postgres таблиц. В идеале хочется иметь поле с типом некоторого pojo класса и при сохранении сущности через репозиторий иметь автоматическую конвертацию в json-type поле таблицы и наоборот.

Comment: Гугл в помощь:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/234841/
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16049086/1341148